# var hoisting Question in javascript and it's output

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering why is it that the output for the 3rd console.log is 2?
I know that var statements are hoisted (without their value initialization) to the top of the global or function scope it belongs to, even when it’s inside a with or catch block. I'm still currently studying javascript at the moment and no one can explain to me properly, since I was expecting that the value of the last 2 console.log is undefined. Why is it that the 2nd console.log is undefined and the last console.log output is 2? Why the last one is able to access the value of y inside the catch block?

```js
(function () {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (x) {
        var x = 1, y = 2;
        console.log(x);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
})();
```

Comment: If you do `catch (foo)` instead of `catch (x)` you'll see an interesting result.

Comment: I assume `catch(x)` has something to do with it

Answer (score 2):

Both `x,y` are hoisted. `var` is function scoped so they will be hoisted without initialization at top of the block.

```js
  (function () {
        var x,y;
        try {
            throw new Error();
        } catch (x) {
            x = 1;
            y = 2;
            console.log(x);
        }
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
    })();
```

You have a local variable in the `catch` block due to catch(x).
When you do `x=1` inside the `catch` block, you are only changing the value of your local `x` (the one which is the parameter to the catch block). The inner `x` shadows the outer `x`. The outside `x` is still `undefined`. Updating `y` will update the outer one, hence your output.

Answer (score 1):

The explaination has everything to do with variable hoisting and assignment.

In the catch block, variable **y** is hoisted to the function-level of the annonymous function

Since your catch block is written as "**catch (x)**" the **var** statement is assigning its local value of **x** within the catch block to **1**. That is why the first **console.log(x)** returns **1**.

The way your code is written, variable **x** is **undefined** on the function-level resulting in the second **console.log(x)** returning **undefined**.

variable **y** *is* being hoisted to the function level (despite the assignment appearing in the **var** line withing the catch block. So the **var** assignment in the catch block is storing the value of **y** as **2** at the function-level.

That is why it is appearing as **2** in your third **console.log** statement.

Please see the following code examples with the introduction of a **z** variable within the try/catch blocks

Example #1:

```
(function () {
    try {
        var z='before';
        throw new Error();
        var z='after';
    } catch (x) {
        var x = 1, y = 2
        console.log(x);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(z);
})();
```

where **console.log(z)** will respond with '**before**'

Example #2:

```
(function () {
    try {
        var z='before';
        throw new Error();
        z='after';
    } catch (x) {
        var x = 1, y = 2, z='catch'
        console.log(x);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(z);
})();
```

where **console.log(z)** will respond with '**catch**'

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you! So basically, the catch(x) makes the assigning of value of x inside the catch block local only and will not modify the function variable at the function scope.

Answer (score 1):

In JS `var` has a function scope so you can access `y` anywhere in the function.
For `x` you have two separate variables one in `catch(x)` and the second is initialized in the inside catch.